# How do I remove the long name given to my internet connection?

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

The other day my computer randomly started displaying the full name of my ethernet controller as you can see here:

[image: image of problem]

I'm fine with it saying Ethernet Controller like it used to but having the whole name including my motherboard is a bit overkill and makes the dialog huge. My question is how do I revert this back to default to make the dialog smaller the way it used to be?

Comment: Which system is this? Looks like elementaryOS.

Comment: It's just stock ubuntu 15.10 with a few themes thrown on top of it.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/354783/why-is-network-interface-loaded-as-rename3

Comment: Can you not click "Edit connections" on the bottom of the menu in your screenshot and change its name from there?

Answer (score 0):

Choose **Edit connections..." on the bottom of the menu, then you will see a list of connections:

[image]

Highlight the connection with unapropriate name, and click **Edit**. Now Just rename the interface in the settings window:

[image]

Now, rename, OK, OK, **DONE**

Comment: Nope!, this wont work. It will change the name "Wired connection 1" (see image in Q) not the Ethernet controller name being displayed.

Comment: thanks @Rinzwind for embed screenshots.. I didn't have enough karma to add them right to the answer...

Comment: @SeverusTux, yep... Sad, but it's true...